# What is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by $v_1= (2, -1,1)$ and $v_2= (1,2,3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by $v_1=(2, -1,1)$ and $v_2=(1,2,3)$?

my options:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe5kV.jpg]

$[\vec v_1,\vec v_2]=\{(x,y+1,x-y); x,y\in\mathbb R\}$
$[\vec v_1,\vec v_2]=\{(x,y,x+y); x,y\in\mathbb R\}$
$[\vec v_1,\vec v_2]=\{(0,y,z); x,y\in\mathbb R\}$
$[\vec v_1,\vec v_2]=\{(x,y,y-3); x,y\in\mathbb R\}$
$[\vec v_1,\vec v_2]=\{(x,y,5); x,y\in\mathbb R\}$

tried calculate 10 times but none managed to get there one of these results

```
2a+b = x
-a +2b = y
a+3b= z
\/
   -a +2b = y
+   a +3b = z
       5b = y+z
        b = (y+z)/5
```

Comment: try to see if $v_1$ and $v_2$ belong to any of the options? look at $b$

Comment: Since all the options have dimension two, you only have to see in which ones the two considered vectors belong.

Comment: where you seed two?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do these things is by elimination: the sets in (a),(d),(e) are not even subspaces (why? Check whether they contain the zero vector...), and taking $\,v_1\,$ (which, of course, belongs to any subspace generated by it and other vectors), we can rule out (c), so the answer **must** be (b).

**Another way:** From basic analytic geometry we know the space we're looking for is the plane

$$\pi:=t\,\overline{v_1}+s\,\overline{v_2}=t(2,-1,1)+s(1,2,3)\;,\;\;t,s\in\Bbb R\implies$$

$$\pi=\left\{(2t+s\,,\,-t+2s\,,\,t+3s)\;;\;t,s\in\Bbb R\right\}$$

and for a general element in the plane it's easy to see the third coordinate equals the sum of the first two...

Comment: (5,6,7) != (5,6,5+6)

Comment: yES @CiroVargas, I know... so **what** ?

Comment: then this equation dont generate elements of R³?

Comment: Ciro, I'm not sure what you are asking: my answer refers to the subspace generated by $\,v_1,v_2\,$ . It *obviously* cannot generate the whole $\,\Bbb R^3\,$ ...!

Comment: that's ok, but how to i can do a inverse? I did not understand his explanation. sorry

Comment: @Ciro Vargas, what inverse? Si hablas español quizás así nos podamos entender mejor...

Answer (score 0):

The subspace generated be $v_1$ and $v_2$ is

$$\bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix}
        2r + s \\
        -r + 2s  \\
        r + 3s \\
        \end{pmatrix} : r,s \in \mathbb{R}\bigg\}$$

and $(2r + s) + (-r + 3s) = r + 3s$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: i tried (2a +b, -a +2b, a +3b) and solving the systems but fail

Comment: @CiroVargas Let $x =2r + s$, $y = -r + 2s$.  Then $r + 3s = x + y$.

Answer (score 0):

It comes as a plane,  (2,-1,1) and (1,2,3) both fall in such a plane.

The general process to solve this sort of problem is to take the determinate of a matrix, whose first row is the vector (x,y,z), and the other two rows give (2,-1,1) and (1,2,3).

Since ultimately the determinate gives the volume of the parallelopied formed by the three vectors, it comes to find the value which gives 0.  Any vector that gives a value of 0 falls in the same plane as the two named vectors.

```
     | x   y   z  |          x (-3 -2)
 det | 2  -1   1  |   =    + y ( 1 -6)   =  -5x -5y + 5z = 0
     | 1   2   3  |        + z ( 4 +1)
```

One then simplifies by multiplying by $-1/5$ to get $x+y-z=0$.  This can be tested against the vectors to show that both match this.

Any point that solves this equation gives a position vector.  For example, (1,0,1) is both a point on the plane, and a vector constructable in these other two.

Comment: How do I generate a vector from this equation? is not possible to generate a vector? only zero vectors (0,0,0)?

Comment: any set of numbers, (x,y,-x-y) will do.  It's a position vector on a plane.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to solve the system. If you have a subspace generated by vectors you write a random vector being a linear combination of these vectors. So, in this case, you can say, if a, b, x, y and z belongs to the set of the real numbers, that:

a(2,-1,1) + b(1,2,3) = (x,y,z)

This implies that:

2a +  b = x (1)

-a + 2b = y (2)

a + 3b = z (3)

Now, if you are afraid or, i don't know what, of using Cramer's Rule or Gauss' Elimination to solve the system, you can do it by the simple way, but have to remember that you have to work with all equations of the system to solve it.

So, adding equation (2) in (3), you have:

5b = y + z (4)

And, adding 2 times the equation (2) in (1), you have:

5b = x + 2y (5)

Now, subtracting (4) of (5), you have:

-1(5b) + 5b = -1(y + z) + x + 2y

0 = x + y - z

Calling S, the subspace of R3 generated by these vectors, you can say:

S = {(x,y,z); with x,y,z on R; and x+y-z=0}

If you isolate z, you have: z = x + y.
So, S turns the same of:

S = {(x,y,x+y); with x,y on R}

That is a simpler way to indentify the subspace, because there's no x+y-z=0, and no z in the set, but saying the same thing.